# Spring MVC throws 404 NOT_FOUND while looking for JSP files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

In a simple Spring Core MVC Project (No Spring Boot, no XML configuration) I got 404 NOT_FOUND while trying to access to a URL declared in a controller, and it says that cannot find the JSP File.

Here's the console output:

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG DispatcherServlet - GET "/appmutualista/socios/showSocios", parameters={}
[http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to dev.lorena.projects.appmutualista.controller.SocioController#showSocios()
[http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG JstlView - View name 'socios', model {}
[http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG JstlView - Forwarding to [/webapp/view/socios.jsp]
[http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

The controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/socios")
public class SocioController {
    
    @GetMapping("/showSocios")
    public String showSocios() {
        return "socios";
    }
}
```

The ViewResolver bean in @Configuration class:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/webapp/view/");
    internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return internalResourceViewResolver;
 }
```

And the project structure:

[image: The Project Structure]

I am using embedded Tomcat 9 and JDK 8 to run the APP. After hours, I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Usually project has next hierarhy:

```
src
     `-- main
         |-- java
         |   `-- ...
         |-- resources
         |   `-- ...
         `-- webapp
             |-- ...
```

And it is better to make same hierarhy in your code.
In this case root is `webapp` folder for `InternalResourceViewResolver`

```
internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/view/")
```

Jsp should be in `webapp` hierarhy, due to different behaviour in case of store you jsp in resources folder (war and jar package store this jsp in different places in builder war and jar).

Comment: Moved webapp to main folder and set the preffix to "/view/" but getting the same error.